# Ubuntu installed fos but when import it, no shader

Tags: python, ubuntu

I installed fos using github version, however when I tried to import fos, I got error said that no module named `shader.lib`, do I need to install a different version of it?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on your problem? What is “fos”, where do I find it? What exactly have you tried and what exactly does the log output look like when your problem appears?

Comment: @Chriki thank you for your reply. fos is library which you can find here https://github.com/fos/fos-legacy ; It was like this: from fos.shader.lib import * ImportError: No module named shader.lib; I just type in import fos using python

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have downloaded Fos to `/home/litaoshen/Fos` and also *successfully* built it there (as indicated in the `README` that comes with Fos, run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` and make sure that there are no errors). Then you should be able to run the following commands in a shell without any errors:

```sh
export PYTHONPATH=/home/litaoshen/Fos
python -c 'import fos ; from fos.shader.lib import *'
```

This should not generate any output.

Your comment above suggests that you have not set your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable (cf. [`man python`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/python.1.html#contenttoc6)).

Comment: @litaoshen Have you already gotten round to trying my answer?